# Best WordPress theme framework for correct display of CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, evaluating-civicrm, theme

For those who develop for CiviCRM on WordPress, what theme frameworks do not work with CiviCRM, what theme frameworks do work without problems, and which seem best for displaying CiviCRM content?

I've looked at Genesis, and Gantry.

Comment: Well I know that some themes don't work at all. You have to check everything, including the appearance of the public facing contribution forms. I have used iconic-one, seems to work okay.

Comment: I've never had issues with any WordPress theme in terms of functionality, including free and premium ones, however you might run into styling issues with not so well designed/implemented ones. A few premium I tested myself: Genesis, X-Theme, and Divi.

Comment: The Virtue theme has styling issues, that's what I meant by not working in my first comment.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. We have good displays also with Twenty Fourteen.

Comment: Thank you Paul and Andrei.  I guess you just have to try any theme out and see what happens.

Comment: This question probably falls under "primarily opinion-based", but thanks for posting it - should end up as a handy resource - I know there's been one or two questions about WP themes not playing nicely with CiviCRM! Knowing what to look for would be great, so would making CiviCRM behave in those themes :D

Comment: I would encourage folks who posted comments naming specific themes to repost as answers!

Comment: Asking for the "best" is subjective, when you haven't identified what would make one theme better than any other. StackExchange questions need to be definitively answerable, rather than polls.

Comment: I have changed the answer to a community wiki in order encourage collaboration on a response to this useful query that does not match the StackExchange Q & A format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch out for themes or plugins that use Backbone.JS calls. They seem to be causing some issues right now.  One such theme is Salient.

The JetPack plugin also seems to be suffering from the same problems. (Search the StackExchange for backbone and you'll see a few different threads.)

The Virtue theme has styling issues.

Twenty Fourteen provides good displays.

Comment: Guess I should have put in a link to the original Wiki page for this stuff:  https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+plugins+incompatible+with+CiviCRM

Comment: Now found at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=120029201

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience Genesis, X-Theme and Divi work just fine, no functionality/styling issues so far.

Answer (score 2):

Avada, Divi, X theme, Genesis, Virtue and in general most well-developed WordPress themes work fine. I think BeTheme is OK too.

The Slider Revolution plugin causes JS problems and can be disabled and replaced easily. A lot of commercial themes bundle this plugin.

You can still expect to do some work making CiviCRM pages display nicely because CiviCRM uses it's own CSS and classes - this can be disabled using CiviCRM Admin Utils in WordPress. This is not a WordPress theme problem, that's a CiviCRM design decision which has been discussed at length in Github.