# wordpress/civicrm mobile optimi2ed themes

Tags: contacts, activities, mobile

The existing thread is stale (2017), a lifecycle ago in internet terms.  Seeking theme which enables contact search/edit/update functionality and activity add via mobile theme.

civicrm mobile access on wordpress 2019 is cumbersome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best WordPress theme framework for correct display of CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/best-wordpress-theme-framework-for-correct-display-of-civicrm)